# STM32F4461re: mapping peripheral register using structures. I need to understand the meanings of the pointers

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I have two questions.

**First question:**

I am writing the code for the mapping of the peripheral and I come across to simple code like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    __IO uint32_t MODER;
    __IO uint32_t OTYPER;
    __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;
    __IO uint32_t PUPDR;
    __IO uint32_t IDR;
    __IO uint32_t ODR;
    __IO uint32_t BSRR;
    __IO uint32_t LCKR;
    __IO uint32_t AFR[2];

}GPIO_Typedef;
```

and

```
#define GPIOA           ((GPIO_TypeDef*)) GPIOA_BASE)
```

what is the use of the pointer? Usually what I have come across is that if you typecast a pointer you have

```
double *c;
int *p = (int*) c;
```

So how typecasting and pointers are used here? Thanks for the answers!

**Second question:**

I have seen this code on another thread.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned IN; /* offset 0 */
    unsigned _unused1[3];
    unsigned OUT; /* offset 0x10 */
    unsigned _unused2[3];
    unsigned DIR; /* offset 0x20 */
} PortStruct;

#define PORTA (*(volatile PortStruct *)0x80001000))
#define PORTB (*(volatile PortStruct *)0x80002000))
```

What the second * is used for? I have heard it is used for dereferencing, does that mean that it takes the value inside the pointed register instead of the address?

Answer (score 3):

The typedef describes a variable with a intricatly designes structure.
It is designed so that the internal layout reflects exactly a part of the memory-mapped peripheral array of your environment.

The problem with using it directly is that defining any variable of that type will end up creating a variable anywhere, but not in the peripheral array. Specifically not at the precise location you need it to be located, at the address you find in e.g. in `PORTA` and `PORTB`.

However, you do not need the compiler/linker to create a variable there, you can get them to trust you that such a variable exists exactly in the right place.
That is done with the special definition of `PORTA`.

If you use `PORTA` in code it gets expanded by preprocessor to
`(*(volatile PortStruct *)0x80001000))`.

It means
"Dear compiler, please

- take this literal number
- consider it to be a pointer to a variable of type `PortStruct`
- dereference it"

In effect, using `PORTA` can be used like using a variable of type `PortStruct` which happens to be exactly at the right address.

The second `*` you ask about is the dereferencing, which turns what is conisdered a pointer into what can be used as a variable.

Comment: @Houst For clarity the dereference allows you to write `PORTA.OUT = 0x01` for example, whereas for the `GPIOA` definition that lacks a dereference you would write `GPIOA->MODER = 0x01` or somewhat perversely perhaps `*GPIOA.MODER = 0x01`.  The nature of the port definitions (pointer or instance) is more or less arbitrary and an API design, rather than technical decision.